# How to apply Global Pipes during e2e tests

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

How do you apply global pipes when using `Test.createTestingModule`?

Normally, global pipes are added when the application is mounted in `main.ts`.

```
beforeEach(async done => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule]
    }).compile()

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication()
    await app.init()
    done()
  })
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's what I do to ensure that the global pipes in my `main.ts` file are always in sync with my testing setup...

Start by creating a new file called `main.config.ts`, this should contain your global pipes, filters, etc:

```js
import { INestApplication, ValidationPipe } from "@nestjs/common";

export function mainConfig(app: INestApplication) {
  app.enableCors();
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
}
```

Next, use the newly created `mainConfig` function in both the `main.ts` and `app.e2e-spec.ts` (or wherever you setup your tests):

`main.ts`

```js
import { NestFactory } from "@nestjs/core";
import { mainConfig } from "main.config";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  // use here
  mainConfig(app);

  await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();
```

`app.e2e-spec.ts`

```js
import { INestApplication } from "@nestjs/common";
import { TestingModule, Test } from "@nestjs/testing";
import { AppModule } from "app.module";
import { mainConfig } from "main.config";

let app: INestApplication;

beforeEach(async () => {
  const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [AppModule],
  }).compile();

  app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();

  // use here
  mainConfig(app);

  await app.init();
});
```

Now if you need to add a new pipe, you'll only have to make the change in one spot (`main.config.ts`) to see it reflected in both the app and the tests.

Comment: Changed answer to this one, as this is what I do now and its a more DRY implementation.

Answer (score 6):

You can add them before you initialize the testing module:

```
  beforeEach(async done => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule]
    }).compile()

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication()

    // Add global pipe here
    app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true, whitelist: true, forbidNonWhitelisted: true }))

    await app.init()
    done()
  })
```

Comment: There should be a way to automatically include stuff like this from whats in the main.ts

Comment: @CoreyBerigan check out my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72090376/11670977
...
it doesn't automatically include it, but it ensures your tests and main.ts stay in sync.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to declare the global pipes in the module using `APP_PIPE`.

```js
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_PIPE,
      useClass: ValidationPipe,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then it will be available in your e2e tests.