# How to validate if a Param string is a MongoId in Nestjs without DTO

Tags: javascript, mongodb, validation, mongoose, nestjs

I have requests in my controller, the `@Param` is the string version of the MongoId.
If I call this request with an invalid format of the string, not Matching the MongoId format, the request goes through until the MongoDB call throws an internal server Error.

How do I validate that for example `"aaa"` or "ANWPINREBAFSOFASD" is not validated and stops as early as possible in my requests

Current Controller Endpoint:

```js
@Get(':id')
  @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Get nice information' })
  findOne(
    @Param('id') id: string) {
    return this.niceService.findOne(id);
  }
```

The service that is called:

```js
async findOne(id: string): Promise<NiceDocument> {

    const niceResult: NiceDocument = await this.NiceSchema.findById(id)

    if (!niceResult) {
      throw new NotFoundException()
    }
    return table
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this is to use a custom Validation pipe:

Create the pipe and export it:

```js
import { ArgumentMetadata, BadRequestException, Injectable, PipeTransform } from "@nestjs/common";
import {ObjectId} from 'mongodb'

@Injectable()
export class ValidateMongoId implements PipeTransform<string> {
  transform(value: string, metadata: ArgumentMetadata): string{ // Optional casting into ObjectId if wanted!
      if(ObjectId.isValid(value)){
          if((String)(new ObjectId(value)) === value)
              return value;        
          throw new BadRequestException
      }
      throw new BadRequestException
  
  };
}
```

Use the pipe in the controller to validate the string

```js
@Get(':id')
  @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Get nice information' })
  findOne(
    @Param('id', ValidateMongoId) id: string) {
    return this.niceService.findOne(id);
  }
```

Alternatively you could change the returntype in the pipe from string to ObjectId if you are using mongoDB instead of mongoose, mongoose supports requests witht he id in a string format

Answer (score -1):

**use class-validator  in [nestjs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation)**

by using @IsMongoIdObject()
like this:

```
   class ParamDTO{
@IsMongoIdObject()   
id:string
}
```

----Your Funcation---

```
@Get(':id')
  @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Get nice information' })
  findOne(
    @Param() id: ParamDTO) {
    return this.niceService.findOne(id.id);
  }
```

Comment: @IsMongoIdObject does not exist in class validator,  and the Param is not an object per default

And yes solving it with DtO by casting id  like this: 

@Param(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true })) { id }: MongoIdDto) works too, but the goal is to NOT use a DtO / object and validate the string directly

Comment: please read Nestjs doc for validation: [https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation]

Comment: I read through it, but there is no @IsMongoIdObject() in class-validator

Comment: sorry its @IsMongoId() not @IsMongoIdObject()

Comment: yea I figured xD, but there is another problem, making use of app.useGlobalPipes etc. the validation works while manually sending REST requests, but not when using the TestModule? Any suggestions

Comment: im not using testing mode all my test be manual

Comment: ah just FYI I found that you have to add the setting to tests too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59355841/how-to-apply-global-pipes-during-e2e-tests#:~:text=You%20can%20add%20them%20before%20you%20initialize%20the%20testing%20module%3A